# Send request with ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: node.js, svn, visualsvn-server

I have a little problem, the data I want to request from our SVN server (VisualSVN) are encoded as ISO-8859-1, when I try to request them with node.js `https` module it doesn't encode ä, ö, ü, etc. correctly.

My question is, how can I tell node to request the data as ISO-8859-1?

PS: I would like to stick with the buildin components, if this isn't possible, I am open for ideas :)

### edit 1

This the code I use to get files

```
exports.getSvnFile = function (path, auth, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: app.getSetting('svnserver'),
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/svn/' + encodeURIComponent(path).replace(/%2F/g, '/'),
        auth: tools.readFromSession(auth, 'username') + ':' + tools.readFromSession(auth, 'password'),
        headers: {
            'Accept-Charset': 'iso-8859-1'
        }
    }
    try {
        https.request(options, function (res) {
            var result = []
            try {
                console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode)
                console.log('CONTENT-TYPE: ' + res.headers['content-type'])
                var data = ''
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk
                })
                res.on('end', function () {
                    callback(data, res.headers['content-type'])
                })
                res.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                })
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error(ex)
            }
        }).end()
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex)
        callback([])
    }
}
```

The data I get out there are already broken, when the `res.end` part gets called. I thought maybe the `Accept-Charset` header might help but apparently it didn't.

Comment: Do you want to *receive data from* SVN, and node.js does not receive it correctly, or do you want to *send data to* SVN and SVN does not receive it correctly? Please elaborate. Also, show your code so far.

Comment: I want to receive data from Visual SVN, they offer a webapi, which allows to bypass the usual svn checkout/list way :) I will post my code.

Comment: If you want to receive a document from a web server then the `Content-Type` header of the server's response determines the encoding. If SVN announces `Content-Type: foo/bar; charset=ISO-8859-1` then node.js will do the right thing automatically. If SVN does not announce the correct encoding, fix that. You ought not to change anything in the node.js code (especially you shouldn't send an `Accept-Encoding` header, that's completely wrong).

Comment: Maybe it helps if your request the resource in question with a browser, copy the SVN server's response headers and add them to your question.

Comment: That is the weird part, when I request the file with IE or Firefox it shows correct and with the right encoding. So, the encoding should be right. When I request the data with node, my `Content-Type` looks like this: `Content-Type: text/plain`. The `Content-Charset` header isn't set. The `Accept-Encoding` was a (cheap) try, which didn't work...

Comment: Of course it didn't. The web server won't transcode the content for you. If the SVN server does not send a `charset` parameter, the receiving end (node) must assume that the content is UTF-8 encoded (according to the spec). Now if content is *not*, in fact, UTF-8, then the SVN server sends broken responses, technically speaking. Browsers have sophisticated encoding-detection mechanisms that work around the issue by testing the raw byte-stream of the response. That's why it looks OK in the browser.

Comment: Now the problem is, SVN obviously serves files from disk which it does not know the encoding of. That makes it impossible to configure SVN to send a correct `charset` parameter. I would suggest instead of hard-wiring a certain encoding in your node.js code, use a module like this one (https://github.com/mooz/node-icu-charset-detector) to detect the correct charset dynamically. If you don't want to/can't do that, your question becomes *"How to re-interpret a node http response as a different charset?"* and I expect searching for that should give you something.

Comment: Thank you, I gonna try the link out :)

Comment: Well, that was the first hit on Google that seemed to fit. Look around, maybe there are better modules.

Comment: The link doesn't work on Windows :/ Lets see if I find another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have the solution, for me at least it worked :)

Here is the code from above adjusted:

```
exports.getSvnFile = function (path, auth, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: app.getSetting('svnserver'),
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/svn/' + encodeURIComponent(path).replace(/%2F/g, '/'),
        auth: tools.readFromSession(auth, 'username') + ':' + tools.readFromSession(auth, 'password')
    }
    try {
        https.request(options, function (res) {
            var result = []
            res.setEncoding('binary')
            try {
                console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode)
                console.log('CONTENT-TYPE: ' + res.headers['content-type'])
                var data = ''
                res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk
                })
                res.on('end', function () {
                    callback(data, res.headers['content-type'])
                })
                res.on('error', function (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                })
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error(ex)
            }
        }).end()
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex)
        callback([])
    }
}
```

It is nearly identical except of one thing, the encoding is set to `binary` then it worked perfectly :)